# Postgres select 'at least' items

Tags: postgresql

I want to select comments to post, elder then particular commentId, BUT I want to have **at least** 5 comments in result anyway.

So if there are less then 5 comments is sql : `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id >= :comment_id`, I have to make another select `SELECT * FROM comments LIMIT 5`.

Is it possible to get the same logic in one request?

Comment: Can you somehow count id for `comment_id + 5 comments`? Then you could reverse the order and get 5 last comments: SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id > _comment_id + 5 comments_ ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5`

Answer (score 1):

```
with c as (
    select count(*) as c
    from comments
    where id >= :comment_id
)
select *
from comments
where id >= :comment_id
union all
(
    select *
    from comments
    where id < :comment_id
    order by id desc
    limit greatest(5 - (select c from c), 0)
)
;
```

Comment: Sorry, but could you pls explain the request?

Comment: I cant just ctrl+c it, I have to modify it to test, but to modify I need to understand it :(
I havent used `with` instruction before and cant figure out what `limit greatest(5 - (select c from c), 0)` is

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
WITH x AS {
  SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id >= :comment_id
),
y AS (
  SELECT * FROM comments
  LIMIT 5
)
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE 5 <= ( SELECT count(*) FROM x )
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM y
WHERE 5 > ( SELECT count(*) FROM x )
```